# sapui5 vizframe graph to pdf issue

Tags: sapui5

I am unable to convert graph to PDF using `vizFrame` in `sapui5` using version 1.28.30 can't change version due to client. Here is my code please check and please help.

I am getting half of a graph as result PDF. For this i have imported all library which is needed like `canvgg`, `jsPdf`, `rgbColor`, `stackblur.js`.

[image]

```
pressToPdf:function(oEvent){
    var oVizFrame = thatgrowth.getView().byId("ID_GROWTH_CHART_LENGTH_SCALE");   
    var id =  thatgrowth.getView().byId("ID_GROWTH_CHART_LENGTH_SCALE").sId
    var svg  = $("#"+id).find("svg.v-m-root").outerHTML()
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 450);
    canvgg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
     // Generate PDF
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 600, 450);
    doc.save('GrowthChart.pdf');
},
```

Comment: I am getting half of a graph as result PDF.For this i have imported all librarry which is needed like canvgg, jsPdf, rgbColor, stackblur.js. Please help

Comment: Your PDF is *A4* size; which is **595 x 842**. But your image is **600x450**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code sample:

```
pressToPdf:function(oEvent){
    var oVizFrame = thatgrowth.getView().byId("ID_GROWTH_CHART_LENGTH_SCALE");
    var svg  = oVizFrame.getDomRef().getElementsByTagName("svg")[1];
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var bBox = svg.getBBox();
    canvas.width = bBox.width;
    canvas.height = bBox.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillstyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";  //Set the context background
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //Apply background to chart rect
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');   //Save as JPEG instead of base64
        var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');           //A4 landscape 297 x 210
        var imgHeigth = 190 * (bBox.height / bBox.width);
        doc.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 10, 20, 227, 180);  //Download full page chart as PDF
        doc.save('chart_in_pdf');
    };

    imageObj.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + 
          jQuery.sap.encodeURL(svg.outerHTML.replace(/^svg/, 
                              '<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"'));
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PDF is *A4* size; which is **595 x 842** (considering it as 72 PPI). But your image `Canvas` is **600 x 450**. That creates issue. Try reducing the `Canvas` size passed to `doc.addImage` method. Like,

```
doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 590, 450);
```

Comment: @dhilmathy- thanks for looking into it. But reduces size as you said result same output

Comment: @SanUser Have you tried reducing the `Rect` size as well? `context.clearRect(0, 0, 590, 450);`?

Comment: @dhilmathy- yes did same for both.

Comment: I see, the problem is with `Width` & `Height` argument. As per https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#rect, it should be `doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 450, 590);`. Can you try swapping these two args?

Comment: @dhilmathy- yes it is width and height issue , I tried with swapping values also but no rersult

Comment: @SanUser This (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/476) might give you a fix. Similar discussion on Canvas & PDF

Comment: @dhilmathy- okay going through it. Thank you

Comment: @dhilmathy- Got the solution. and thanks for your support

Comment: @SanUser If you could post the answer, will help others.

Comment: How to give horizontal bar on vizframe line chart graph? is there any property ..i have gone through documentation but not succeed.